# C++ Class error in src\class-name.cpp

Tags: c++, class

Have been programming for fun in C++ for almost a year now. However i have avoided classes all the time (Yeah I know, bad idea). 
I have a problem in my .cpp file

```
#include "Password.h"

Password::Password() //<-- error here 
{
    //ctor
}

Password::~Password() //<-- and here
{
    //dtor
}
```

It will give me an error the two mentioned places. The error is "error: prototype for 'Password::Password()' does not match any in class 'Password'"
I have tried to comment every thing out, and the program seems to run fine without it.

Do you guys know what could be wrong? I have been searching for it for several hours now, and could not find anything. 
I am using Code Blocks

Edited with Password.h

```
#ifndef PASSWORD_H

#define PASSWORD_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class Password
{
       protected: /* A password should be protected, right? */
        string password; /* The string to store the password */
        string input; /* The string to store the input */


public:
    /* Constructor, pass a string to it (the actual password) */
    Password (string pass) {this->password = pass;}
    void Input () /* Get the password from the user */
    {
        while (true) /* Infinite loop, exited when RETURN is pressed */
        {
            char temp;
            temp= getch(); /* Get the current character of the password */
            //getline(cin, temp);
            if (cin.get() == '\n') {
            return;
            }
            /* Exit the function */
            input += temp;
            cout << '*'; /* Print a star */
        }
    }
    bool Compare () /* Check if the input is the same as the password */
    {
        if (password.length() != input.length()) /* If they aren't the same length */
            return false; /* Then they obviously aren't the same! */
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= input.length(); i++)
        { /* Loop through the strings */
            if (password[i] != input[i])
                return false; /* If anything is not a match, then they are not the same */
        }
        return true; /* If all checks were passed, then they are the same */
    }
};

#endif // PASSWORD_H
```

This is a bit of code that i got from http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/59437-how-to-make-a-password-show-as-stars/ Credits to him for it.

Comment: What is in your header file `Password.h`? Did you declare this constructor and destructor in there?

Answer (score 4):

`Password::Password() { ... }` will define a function that has been already declared.

For that,

1. the function must have already been  declared (in the `class` declaration for `Password`)--

   - and it should be declared **with an identical signature**, and
2. the function must not be already defined--only declared;

   - otherwise, you will be defining a function twice and the compiler will complain.

In your `.h` file, you have:

```
Password (string pass) {this->password = pass;}
```

Here, you can notice two issues:

1. The signature of this constructor is different than the signature of the constructor defined in the cpp file; the constructor `Password()` *does not exist anywhere* so it cannot be defined in the cpp file!
2. The constructor is already defined, so if you fix the signature of the constructor in your cpp file to include `string pass`, you will see a new error.

---

**To get your CPP code working as-is**

Your `password.h` should change its `class Password` declaration to include:

```
// Password.h
class Password {
public:
    Password(); // default ctor ; declared, not defined
    ~Password(); // default dtor ; declared, not defined
}
```

---

**To have `Password::Password` in the cpp file have the same behavior as the header file**

Change the header file so that:

```
// password.h
...
Password (string pass); // only declared
...
```

and then change the CPP file:

```
Password::Password(std::string pass) { // ctor
}
```